# jquery load from https

Tags: jquery, asp-classic

I am trying to load an https link's html to my client side using jQuery. And my code is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $('#intro').load("https://abc.com/find.asp?param_a=00001&param_b=0002")
});
```

However server responses without anything. Is there something I miss?

Comment: I'm sure you double-checked the URL, but when I try to reach the page you are trying to load, it fails aswell. Maybe this ABC-Server is offline?

Answer (score 1):

[Fiddler] 504 Connection Failed: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 199.181.132.250:443
Timestamp: 08:58:32.184

> 504 Gateway Timeout
>       The server was acting as a gateway or proxy and did not receive a timely response from the upstream server

So, at least at the moment, you won't be able to connect.